# Multiple imputed data set from SPSS to import into MPLUS

Tags: spss, missing-data, factor-analysis, multiple-imputation, mplus

I'm developing a scale for my dissertation project. I need help with how to handle missing data before I start the factor analysis procedure.

Recently I ran a multiple imputation in SPSS (20 iterations). I want to transfer this data into MPLUS to run a factor analysis. I don't know how to tell Mplus this is an imputed data set, or how to prepare data like this. I know Mplus needs tab delimited data.

The new multiple imputed data set contains the original data and 20 copies of data with imputed values.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Im confused why this was closed?

Comment: Probably because the question concerns implementation as opposed a particular methodological/statistical issue.

Comment: @PrestonBotter Thank you!

Comment: I found this https://youtu.be/EmXG2ZGw0GE. Does this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found this video, which was very helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zftIxv532hE